# Preventing all html tags in HTMLPurifier

Tags: htmlpurifier

How to set value of **HTML.ForbiddenElements** so that it would not allow any HTML tags to be entered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to disallow *everything* with HTML Purifier, the easiest way ought to be to set an empty with whitelist [HTML.Allowed](http://htmlpurifier.org/live/configdoc/plain.html#HTML.Allowed) rather than an attempt at a thorough blacklist. (Generally speaking, I'd recommend staying away from blacklist approaches unless you really have no other option - with blacklists, there's always a chance to miss something.)

**But**:

HTML Purifier is a tool designed to help you specifically if you *allow* HTML. If you don't, chances are it is simply computational overhead and doesn't net you a benefit.

To contrast:

Perhaps try `htmlspecialchars(strip_tags(...), ENT_QUOTES, 'your-encoding-goes-here')` instead? That should be faster and just as secure for what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I use `$this->title = strip_tags($this->title);` for title and HTMLPurifier for description. I correctly used from strip_tags? or must use from htmlspecialchars?

Comment: @msoa: Generally speaking, you should use `htmlspecialchars(strip_tags())` because `strip_tags()` alone is not secure. That means if someone genuinely wants to hack your site, they can bypass `strip_tags()`. Of course, if your `$this->title` is already html-escaped later before it's output, then you don't have to do it there (and shouldn't, in fact), but without knowing more about your setup, I can't advise. Good luck! :)